# insert list of dict into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert a list like that ,but much larger.
`list=[{"name":"Tom","gender":"male",},{"name":"Jack","gender":"male",},{"name":"Lee","gender":"male",}]` into MySQL using python,to build a table. I have already import MySQLdb .What should I do then?

Comment: You're really going to have to narrow this down. Is this from that structure into a table with matching column names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have a table named `foo` with `name` and `gender` columns, here is how you can use `executemany()` to insert this list of dictionary into the table:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cursor = db.cursor()

data = [
    {"name":"Tom", "gender":"male"},
    {"name":"Jack", "gender":"male"},
    {"name":"Lee", "gender":"male"}
]
cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO foo (name, gender)
    VALUES (%(name)s, %(gender)s)""", data)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks,it's useful.but when I use it to my own data it don't work.

Comment: My own is like : data=[dict1,dict2,dict3]   dict1= {"name": "Tom","source":u'240907112_1333816867','Title': u'\u300a\u8ba4\u771f\u7684\u300b',"_id":u'47092'}.in MySQL I have already build a table and use _id as primary key .I think it may because there is u in values,but I don't know how to do.

Comment: @GUOJINGWEI please see if it makes sense to create a separate question about trying to apply the proposed solution on your actual data. Thanks.

Comment: I have created a new question hope you can answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525985/insert-list-including-unicode-and-datetime-into-mysql-using-python

Comment: great tanx it worked perFect

Comment: spent what felt like too long on uploading a list of dicts to local mysql and this answer finally worked. Thanks for posting.